# Prove the incorrectness of formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Why this identity is incorrect?
$P\{A|B\} + P\{¬A|¬B\} = 1 $

I know that using Bayes' Formula:
$P\{¬A|¬B\} = (P\{¬A\}*P\{¬B|¬A\})/(P\{A\}*P\{¬B|A\}+P\{¬A\}*P\{¬B|¬A\})$

$ P\{A|B\} = P\{B|A\}*P\{A\}/(P\{A\}*P\{B|A\}+P\{¬A\}*P\{B|¬A\})$ <----Bayes' Formula

But I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the formula is incorrect by giving a counterexample. If you assume that $A=B$ and $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}=P(B)$, then we will have $P(A|B)=1$ and $P(\neg A|\neg B)=1$. The sum is $2$, which is not equal to $1$.